# async callback from SQS queue does not remove the item from the queue

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

When I use an async handler for an SQS queue - the item is not removed from the queue.

e.g. in the following code i see the output from ApproximateReceiveCount slowly increase as messages are reprocessed.

```
export const main = async (event: SQSEvent) => {
  event.Records.map(record=> {
    console.log(`receive count: ${record.attributes.ApproximateReceiveCount}`);
  });

  return 'Done';
};
```

If I remove the async keyword then the messages are properly removed from the queue. What is the correct way to implement an async handler in typescript?

Thanks in advance

p.s. I have the VisibilityTimeout set to 300

Comment: Why `async`? You're not `await`-ing anything

Comment: In the callback I need to call other APIs that return promises so I need to await on their responses